# Update ContextModelSnapshot EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm newer to EF Core, so please forgive me if there is a trivial answer.

**Take this scenario....**

A new web-application is being developed using the latest version of ASP.NET Core, with a code-first approach. At some point, the ContextModelSnapshot became out of sync with the database, due to deletions or source control. We cannot delete the database and recreate it.

**Question:** How can the snapshot be 're-synced' with the database?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can execute the command

`Add-migration temporary`

to create a new empty migration. Then, run

`Remove-Migration temporary` (or their dotnet-cli counterparts)

In recent editions of EF Core (3+), just use:

`Remove-Migration` (will revert the last migration)

It will create model snapshot from scratch even if the migration has already been deleted. This approach works perfectly for Ef core 2.2.0-rtm-35687

Comment: pretty unexpected way to recreate snapshot from database, but works

Comment: This doesn't work because `Add-Migration` cannot be run without a migration name.

Comment: Give it a name with `Add-Migration MyName` The name is not important because Remove-Migration will remove the file.

Comment: Remove-Migration takes no argument, at least in the recent releases of EF Core.

Comment: I am quite puzzled by "It will Revert model snapshot". Did @m-artem mean "It will recreate it from scratch"? Since it was out of sync, I don't see how it could be "reverted" so I assume it's "recreated".

Comment: `Remove-Migration` reverts the changes in the snapshot (EF Core 6). It's very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by merging multiple migrations from different branches + remove migration after merging.
After merge snapshot is Ok, but **migrations designers** are not synced.

If at any point you do remove migration, snapshot is recreated from latest applied migration designer. If designer doesn't contain all previous changes, from that point snapshot is not synced.
When snapshot is not synced, even if you don't have changes in entity model, on adding new migration instead of empty migration you will have migration with already applied changes (but snapshot and migration designer are OK after new migration).

So if you are sure that all changes from entities are applied, solution is to add empty migration:

1. add new migration - this will sync snapshot, migration designer will be ok for future migration removing
2. remove all commands from migration .cs file.

Answer (score -10):

it is so simple just remove ContextModelSnapshot then add new migration

Comment: This is incorrect. If you delete the ContextModelSnapshot and add a new migration, then the new migration will contain ALL the instructions from the previous migrations (making the new migration redundant --and even conflicting-- to the former ones)